# Change encoding in PostgreSQL 9.1

Tags: database, postgresql, encoding

I have the following databases

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "\list"

                             List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+---------+-------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | LATIN1   | en_US   | en_US | 
 template0 | postgres | LATIN1   | en_US   | en_US | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | LATIN1   | en_US   | en_US | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)
```

How can I change encoding from LATIN1 to UTF8 in the database `template1` or `template0`?

Comment: are you aware that those are very special databases, no? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you don't appear to have any actual data here, just shutdown and delete the cluster (server and set of databases) and re-create it. Which operating system are you using? The standard PostgreSQL command to create a new cluster is initdb, but on Debian/Ubuntu et al you'd typically use `pg_createcluster`

See also [How do you change the character encoding of a postgres database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090858/how-do-you-change-the-character-encoding-of-a-postgres-database)

Although you *can* try to tweak the encodings, it's not recommended. Even though I suggested it in that linked question, if you had data with latin1 characters here, you'd need to recode them to utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

update pg_database set encoding = pg_char_to_encoding('LATIN1') where datname = 'seguros'