# Postgres issue encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "LATIN1"

Tags: postgresql, encoding, latin1

Our postgres production database server has a database called crd_production which is born out of the `template1` template database. Incidentally, on an Ubuntu 12.04 box, the default encoding of the template1 and template0 databases on initial creation of the pgcluster had a default encoding of LATIN1. I had dropped the `template1` db and created it afresh with an utf-8 encoding as you can see below.

```
      Name      |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges   
----------------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 crd_production | deployer | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 postgres       | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 template0      | postgres | LATIN1   | en_US      | en_US      | =c/postgres          +
                |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1      | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
(4 rows)
```

We eventually deployed our rails(3.2.11) app and started using the `crd_production` db as the primary database. There is no issue when ActiveRecord is writing/reading data but when I try to fire any sql query from `psql` command line on this db, the following error occurs -

```
crd_production=# select * from users;
ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xe2 0x80 0x9c in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "LATIN1" 

crd_production=# select * from features;
ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xe2 0x80 0x99 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "LATIN1"
```

What could be the problem here? Is it an issue with the client?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

As guessed, the problem was with the client_encoding on the database.

```
crd_production=# show client_encoding;
 client_encoding 
-----------------
 LATIN1
(1 row)
```

To change the client encoding to UTF-8, you need to do this

```
crd_production=#  SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET
```

Check again

```
crd_production=# show client_encoding;
 client_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)
```

Things work fine now.

Comment: See if you can do an alter user set client_encoding='UTF8'; to make this sticky from now on.  Or an alter database if you'd rather.

Comment: I have the same error, but when I tried to check the client_encoding, it was showing me `UNICODE` instead of `LATIN1`. Hmmm.

Comment: @ScottMarlowe FYI, that doesn't seem to be working for me: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36922248/1157054

Comment: Hi, I am a bit confused about this client_encoding and server_encoding, can anyone explain the difference ?

Answer (score 10):

I have same case before with ruby on rails on postgresql 10. This is the trick

```
update pg_database set encoding = pg_char_to_encoding('UTF8') where datname = 'thedb'
```

Source : [How do you change the character encoding of a postgres database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090858/how-do-you-change-the-character-encoding-of-a-postgres-database)

Comment: Worth making a note that this approach actually changes the encoding of the database, rather than just your (local?) client. That may cause issues for other people using the database and assuming another encoding! Unless you're sure this is OK, change the client as papdel's answer suggests.