# How do I change the default client_encoding in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to change the default value for the `client_encoding` configuration variable for a PostgreSQL database I'm running. I want it to be `UTF8`, but currently it's getting set to `LATIN1`.

The database is already set to use UTF8 encoding:

```
application_database=# \l
                                                 List of databases
           Name       |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |          Access privileges
----------------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------
 postgres             | postgres | LATIN1   | en_US       | en_US       |
 application_database | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | postgres=CTc/postgres           +
                      |          |          |             |             | application_database=Tc/postgres
 template0            | postgres | LATIN1   | en_US       | en_US       | =c/postgres                     +
                      |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1            | postgres | LATIN1   | en_US       | en_US       | =c/postgres                     +
                      |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

Which [according to the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-CLIENT-ENCODING) should *already* result in the client using UTF8 as its default `client_encoding` (emphasis mine):

> `client_encoding (string)`
>
> Sets the client-side encoding (character set). **The default is to use the database encoding.**

But it doesn't:

```
$ sudo psql --dbname=application_database
psql (9.1.19)
Type "help" for help.

application_database=# SHOW client_encoding;
 client_encoding
-----------------
 LATIN1
(1 row)
```

I even tried using `ALTER USER <user> SET ...` to change the default config for the user I'm logging in as:

```
application_database=# ALTER USER root SET client_encoding='UTF8';
ALTER ROLE
application_database=# SELECT usename, useconfig FROM pg_shadow;
         usename      |       useconfig
----------------------+------------------------
 postgres             |
 root                 | {client_encoding=UTF8}
 application_database |
(3 rows)
```

But that also had no effect:

```
$ sudo psql --dbname=application_database
psql (9.1.19)
Type "help" for help.

application_database=# SELECT current_user;
 current_user
--------------
 root
(1 row)

application_database=# SHOW client_encoding;
 client_encoding
-----------------
 LATIN1
(1 row)
```

There's nothing in any of the PSQL files on my system:

```
vagrant@app-database:~$ cat ~/.psqlrc
cat: /home/vagrant/.psqlrc: No such file or directory
vagrant@app-database:~$ cat /etc/psqlrc
cat: /etc/psqlrc: No such file or directory
vagrant@app-database:~$ sudo su
root@app-database:/home/vagrant# cat ~/.psqlrc
cat: /root/.psqlrc: No such file or directory
```

I'm running PosgreSQL 9.1:

```
application_database=# SELECT version();
                                                   version
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.1.19 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Okay, so first things first: why isn't setting the user or database encoding having any effect?

Turns out it's because of this line from [the psql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-psql.html#R2-APP-PSQL-CONNECTING):

> If at least one of standard input or standard output are a terminal, then psql sets the client encoding to "auto", which will detect the appropriate client encoding from the locale settings (LC_CTYPE environment variable on Unix systems). If this doesn't work out as expected, the client encoding can be overridden using the environment variable PGCLIENTENCODING.

So, in fact, your previous configuration changes actually *have* been working, just not in the interactive `psql` console. Try the following command:

```
sudo psql --dbname=application_database -c "SHOW client_encoding;" | cat
```

You should see that the client encoding is actually UTF8:

```
 client_encoding
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)
```

Now run the command again, but without piping it to `cat`:

```
sudo psql --dbname=application_database -c "SHOW client_encoding;"
```

You should get the result:

```
 client_encoding
-----------------
 LATIN1
(1 row)
```

So basically, psql is only using `LATIN1` encoding for commands involving the terminal.

How can you fix this? Well, there are a few possible ways.

One would be to do as the docs suggest and set the `PGCLIENTENCODING` environment variable to `UTF8` somewhere persistent, such as `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` to affect only your user, or `/etc/environment` to affect the whole system (see [How to permanently set environmental variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117467/41141)).

Another option would be to configure your system locale settings to use `en_US.utf8` instead of `en_US` (or equivalent). The method for doing this may vary depending on your system, but usually you can do it by modifying `~/.config/locale.conf` (your user only) or `/etc/default/locale` or `/etc/locale.conf` (system-wide). This will affect more than just postgres, and I believe more closely addresses the root of the problem. You can check your current locale settings by running [`locale`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locale).

One other solution would be to update your psqlrc file to include `SET client_encoding=UTF8;`. That file is located at `~/.psqlrc` (your user only) or `/etc/psqlrc` (system-wide). Note that this method won't affect the result of the command we were using to the client encoding earlier, since [the docs state](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-psql.html#R1-APP-PSQL-3) (emphasis mine):

> `--command=command`
>
> Specifies that psql is to execute one command string, command, and then exit. This is useful in shell scripts. **Start-up files (`psqlrc` and `~/.psqlrc`) are ignored with this option.**

Answer (score 8):

Did you set `client_encoding` in `postgresql.conf` (and reload config or restart)? Make sure it's UTF8 not utf8

What is the result of `cat ~/.psqlrc` and `cat /etc/psqlrc` ?

I know you're looking for server-side default, but on the client, you can set an OS envvar:

`export PGCLIENTENCODING=UTF8`

to do this for all users (on that machine), put that in `/etc/profile`

Comment: "What is the result of cat ~/.psqlrc and cat /etc/psqlrc ?" Added to question

Comment: Appending `client_encoding = 'UTF8'` to `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf` and restarting Postgres with `/etc/init.d/postgresql restart` had no effect. Client encoding for new connections is still `LATIN1`. Setting the environment variable did work, but like you said that's specific to the client. Might be "good enough" for my case though...