# Is it safe to change Collation on Postgres (keeping encoding)?

Tags: postgresql, encoding, collation

I have a Postgres 9.3 database which, by mistake, has been set to:

[image]

but I need it to be:

[image]

Since the Encoding doesn't change, it is safe to dump the DB and restore it later (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090858/how-do-you-change-the-character-encoding-of-a-postgres-database)) to a database with the new `Collation` / `Character type`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perfectly safe -- the collation is just telling Postgres which set of rules to apply when sorting text.

You can even set it dynamically on a query basis in the order by clause, and should be able to alter it without needing to dump the database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Anyway it seems it couldn't be changed "on the fly", as per the answer I linked. In fact, on pgAdmin those fields are greyed out.

Comment: That question relates to encoding based on its url. The syntax to change the collation on an existing table is `ALTER [ COLUMN ] column [ SET DATA ] TYPE data_type [ COLLATE collation ] [ USING expression ]`, as [documented here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html).

Comment: I just did the dump-reload method, since I needed to change the stnadard collation of the entire database.