# Novice: PostgreSQL using unicode symbols in a table

Tags: postgresql, unicode

I created the table:

```
jyotish=# CREATE TABLE graha(name varchar(80),english_name varchar(80),symbol char(1));
```

And I try to create a record with the UTF-8 Sun Symbol like this:

```
jyotish=# INSERT INTO graha VALUES('surya','sun','u\2609');
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  value too long for type character(1)
```

How do I put UTF-8 symbols in a column?

Comment: Your unicode escape syntax is invalid. In fact, there is no language, which works that way (some may accept `'\uXXXX'` as a unicode escape, but not `'u\XXXX'`). Postgresql uses the [standard-compatible syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-UESCAPE): `U&'\XXXX'` [by default](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS).

Answer (score 1):

> I get the error:
>
> ERROR:  value too long for type character(1)

If your problem is above then,

You have assigned the length of character in column `symbol` to `1`(`symbol char(1)`), so you can only insert values with length of `1`

in your insert statement you've trying to insert `'u\2609'`(`length=6`) to column `symbol` it's not possible

solution : `ALTER TABLE graha ALTER COLUMN symbol  TYPE character varying(100);`

---

> How do I put UTF-8 symbols in a column?

Create Database with UTF-8 encoding

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
```

or you want to alter the existing database then see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5090923/3682599)