# postgresql 12.3 convert existing DB to use case-insensitive collation?

Tags: database, postgresql, collation, case-insensitive

postgresql 12.3 in Liux container (Alpine 3.10)

I would like to convert an existing DB to use case-insensitive collation. Is it possible? I mean, without dropping the database and recreating from scratch.

Also: if it's possible to do at a table or a field level, that's also fine, but again, without dropping and recreating the table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you change the character encoding of a postgres database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090858/how-do-you-change-the-character-encoding-of-a-postgres-database)

Comment: No.  First, I am not changing encoding, I am changing case-insensitive collation. Second, the answer suggests dropping and recreating the db.

Comment: There is no alter database statement that allows to change the default collation. You can alter each column 1 by one, but you'd also need to include the collation when creating new columns/tables. Recreating is still the better solution.

Comment: And if I don't mind to ALTER columns one by one, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You could change to a *[nondeterministic](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#COLLATION-NONDETERMINISTIC)* collation, but since that seems to not be available you can install the *[citext extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/citext.html#id-1.11.7.17.5)*, then alter your columns to type citext.

```
create extension if not exists citext. 
alter table *table_name* alter column *column_name* set data type citext';
```

Full example follows. I attempted to create a fiddle. However, citext did not exist and I did not have authority to install the extension.

```
create extension if not exists citext; 

create table test_ci( col1 text, col2 citext);
insert into test_ci(col1,col2)
   ( values ('ABC','XyZ'), ('ABc','lll'), ('Abc','LLL'), ('abc','xYz'))
   
select *
  from test_ci 
 where col1 = 'ABC';

select *
  from test_ci 
 where col2 = 'XYZ';

alter table test_ci alter col1 set data type citext;
select *
  from test_ci 
 where col1 = 'ABC';
```