PostgreSql accent issue
SELECT LOWER(p."Name") FROM "User" p WHERE LOWER(p."Name") LIKE 'admin%'; 
In this query, I want to retrieve the data from "ADMIN" as "admin", but it comes as "admİn". There is an accent problem. How can I solve this globally in my database? Valid for all tables. I don't want to use the unaccent function because I'm using it via .Net.
I tried the Unaccent function, but I can't write this in every query.
Example


Does this answer your question? Does PostgreSQL support "accent insensitive" collations?

The encoding seems to be the problem.
You can refer to the official PostGres documentation

How can I change an existing database?

see ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090858/how-do-you-change-the-character-encoding-of-a-postgres-database
